# Nautilus Crashes on Searching

Tags: nautilus

On Ubuntu Gnome in Nautilus I Pressed `Ctrl+F` and searched for **system-c** and then nautilus closed. Is this a bug with nautilus or problem with my computer.
Also if i type any word after **system-** , nautilus crashes.

Comment: Problem suddenly got worse on Nautilus 3.26.4

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem. I reinstalled it and now it works:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

Comment: First I had the impression that the reinstall worked for me, but now I am back to getting frequent crashes when typing filenames in the nautilus file browser.

Comment: worked for me! let's see if it keeps on working

Comment: still the same issue.

Comment: It doesn't work. Even in ubuntu 20.04 ...same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This apparently has been solved and the fix is on the way out. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1795028

Comment: The issue is still there in ubuntu 20.04. Nautilius crashes while I type in search box in a local directory.