# Nautilus crashing during seach

Tags: nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome on Wayland. When I open Nautilus and click on the search icon and then start to enter the search criteria, Nautilus simply crashes and disappears from the desktop after the first few letters are input. I have re-booted but the problem persists.

This question is not about the search method that Nautilus uses but about it actually crashing during a search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Traditional search-as-you-type on newer Nautilus versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275883/traditional-search-as-you-type-on-newer-nautilus-versions)

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. My question is about Nautilus crashing and that isn't mentioned in the link you offered.

Comment: Does it crash when running on X.Org instead of Wayland?

Comment: I confirm this. Not related to Wayland or Xorg - I am on xorg. During the session, it craches the first time (or few times) when searching with few letters, and later in the session, crashes on searching occur less frequently. Strange there are very few reports on this.

Comment: Question also asked before: https://askubuntu.com/questions/879385/nautilus-crashes-on-searching but without accepted answer, thus so far not a duplucate

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus crashing during a search [is a known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1795028). As of now, the bug is being fixed. The issue is marked as fixed, and is rolling out in nautilus - 1:3.26.4-0ubuntu5 for the upcoming cosmic release. A fix for for the LTS release 18.04 also appears to be on its way.