# Nautilus crash when searching (again ? seems like old 2018 bug...)

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I hope you and your families are well,

Going from 16.04 to 18.04 Ubuntu yesterday I'm discovering today that Nautilus crashes when looking for files (search button then type one or two letters : Nautilus freezes)

This only happens with a normal user. NO PROBLEM when using Nautilus as super user.

I reinstalled software (sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus) : no change

It looks like Issue described here : [Nautilus crashing during seach](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081686/nautilus-crashing-during-seach?newreg=441727b784b647ef8f5c69ad5097bae5). In 2018 Answer was "Issue has been fixed", perhaps It may not have been...

Looking for help, I'm a beginner. Thanks, take care !

Laurent

Comment: Nautilus shipping with 18.04 is older than the version of Gnome Shell, and indeed unfortunatelly is a poor and buggy version. Live with it for a few weeks, and then move to Ubuntu 20.04, the next long term release, with a *much* improved desktop and nautilus. Note that your question may be closed here, because this is a bug, and we do not do bugs here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I've installed "mate-search-tool", looks fine.
I'm going to live with this situation until 20.04 version.
Have a nice day,