# Gnome Files crashes when searching files Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus, search

I have the following problem: When I want to do a search, via the Files application on Gnome, my window crashes without any error message (approx. 1 second after I type my first letter in the search bar). I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and I already reinstalled Nautilus, as described here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/879385/nautilus-crashes-on-searching
However, this did not solve the problem, and I did not find any other solution.
Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

EDIT:
I just want to add that I figured out that not all folders are affected. When I search e.g. in /home or /home/Downloads, then this error does not occur.

Besides this, the error still exists, and is very annoying.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you other than file a bug with Canonical.. stackoverflow is not going to likely have a solution for this is Canonical isn't aware.. I too have had certain folders which crash because of too many files (images) .. making me force quit.. best course of action is report it to the upstream

Comment: Hi Erik, that's actually a great response, thank you a lot. I couldn't solve it until now, and I didn't feel like re-installing everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset Nautilus  settings to default values and it should work well.
NB:Remember that resetting Nautilus settings will remove any synchronisation you have you made, so it's good idea to do back up of important configuration so as to restore them later.

Run the following command:

gronfield reset -f /org/gnome/nautilus/